# Ubercart Product import containing HTML formatting in product description

Tags: 7, ubercart, feeds

Help me to import ubercart product import with product description contains html styling.

Currently I am using [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) and [Ubercart Feed Mappers](https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_feeds).

Source data in excel format.

I try to import CSV file but all the styling and bullet points are not showing correctly.

So I need to import product information with long text and style.

which format should i use to upload this type of Style Information.

Comment: and where is the question, what is the problem?

Comment: @Geoff I have updated the question