# How to import Product Kit via CSV file?

Tags: 7, ubercart, feeds, importing-exporting

I am trying to import product kit from CSV file but I am not getting how to import it as I need to link with products in product kit.

I am using [Ubercart](https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart), [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) and Ubercart product mapper to import.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

## Ubercart Feeds Mapper module:

Refer to the answer to the question about "[How to import products to UberCart 3 using CSV data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274371/how-to-import-products-to-ubercart-3-using-csv-data)". It contains a link to [Drupal 7 Port of uc_feeds](https://www.drupal.org/node/1187096), which seems to include everything that's needed to make this to work by using the [Ubercart Feeds Mapper](https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_feeds) module.

Note: from your recent question "[Ubercart Product import containing HTML formatting in product description](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/162993)", I'm assuming that you are referring to the [Ubercart Feeds Mapper](https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_feeds) module (instead of "Ubercart 'product' mapper" ...

## From Ubercart.org:

[Importing from CSV files](http://www.ubercart.org/docs/user/11089/import_products_csv_format) also details the steps required for such import. The process consists of 3 steps. Here is a summary of these steps:

- Prepare product data.
- Activate the [Node Import](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_import) module.
- Import process.

Attention, the 'Node Import' module does not have a D7 version, only a D6 version.

Comment: I am importing product bundle ( product kit ) so in the csv file we need to link with existing products. That's what i want to know